# Can a government censorship body be called a "watchdog"?

Tags: meaning

In [a recent article](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2015/aug/25/russia-bans-wikipedia-drug-charas-https), The Guardian calls [Roskomnadzor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Service_for_Supervision_in_the_Sphere_of_Telecom,_Information_Technologies_and_Mass_Communications) an « online watchdog ».

Roskomnadzor (*Federal Service for Supervision in the Sphere of Telecom, Information Technologies and Mass Communications*) is a Russian federal executive body responsible for overseeing the media, it has made itself famous for shortly censoring Wikipedia and Github.

I understand that Roskomnadzor's job is to *watch* everything *online*, but I am not sure the term *online watchdog* is appropriate in that case. Is it? Can a government body in charge of consorship (affecting people with no power) ever be called a watchdog? Does not watchdog mean reporting about higher powers?

[image: Roskomnadzor's emblem. At least it should be called watcheagle]

Comment: A *watchdog*, metaphorically, is simply someone or something that monitors and reports on someone or something else for bad behavior. Whether or not it can be applied to a particular authority is going to depend on your predisposition to the judgment and writ of that authority. As such, I think this question is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, a "watchdog agency" is an official arm of the government that protects citizens from the overreach by other parts of the government or by private organizations regulated by the government.  An example of the former is the General Accountability Office (GAO), which audits executive agencies to make sure that appropriated monies are spent properly.  An example of the latter is the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau (CFPB), which investigates the misdeeds of banks.

It is downright Orwellian to apply the word "watchdog" to a claque of government censors who spy on private parties to enhance government control at the expense of individual freedom.  Presumably *Roskomnadzor* is an agency in the Ministry of Truth, which reminds you that we have always been at war with Eastasia.

Comment: I disagree.  For one thing, the sentence didn't say "watchdog *agency*", and for another, the context wasn't the U.S.  If we go back to the original meaning of *watchdog*, it seems like a reasonable use of the word.

Comment: 1. Yes, the sentence (and the article, in fact) doesn't say "agency," but that's what it is -- part of the Russian executive in charge of controlling the media. 2. Yes, the context isn't US, but AmE goes a long way here in establishing meaning, and I could be convinced by evidence that other flavors of English provide a different connotation.   Got any? 3. A watchdog isn't a dog that watches; it's a dog that watches out for, i.e., protects.  Calling part of the Russian internal spying apparat by the term "watchdog" is practically the definition of "Orwellian."

Comment: By the way, @aparente001, your dedication to protecting the reputation of the organs of state has been noted, and your name has been forwarded with approval to the Central Committee.

Comment: Well, good thing I use a pseudonym, then.

Comment: There are plenty of black market operations that have actual dog watchdogs.  The thing that the watchdogs "guard" don't have to be morally approved by us, for us to be able to call the dogs "watchdogs".

Comment: @aparente001 We're not talking about actual dogs or about bodyguards.

Comment: I am!  I argued for going back to the original (literal, canine) meaning and going from there.

Comment: @aparente001 Clearly, you are.  But the OP is asking about a figurative usage concerning an instrument of the state.  There's no path to understanding the trope that goes through the kennel.

Comment: In physics they often talk about "going back to first principles".  I'm going back to the literal sense of the word.  An animal that is trained to go "bow-wow" when something specific happens.  //  You have strong, well thought-out political views -- good!  Now let's let sleeping watchdogs lie.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28805/discussion-between-deadrat-and-aparente001).

Comment: Okay, but tomorrow if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is an appropriate definition, according to Collins Dictionary

a [watchdog](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/watchdog) is:

> - a person or group of persons that acts as a protector or guardian against inefficiency, illegal practices, etc.
> - (as modifier): *a watchdog committee*.

The Cambridge Dictionary provides  the following definitions:

[Government watchdog](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/government-watchdog):

> - ***UK*** a ​government ​organization that makes ​certain that ​companies in a particular ​industry are obeying the ​law:
>
>   - *The ​energy ​company is likely to be ​prosecuted after an ​investigation being ​carried out by the ​government ​watchdog, the Scottish Environment Protection Agency*.
> - ( ***US*** also government watchdog group, also government watchdog organization) a ​group that watches the ​activities of a particular ​part of ​government in ​order to ​report ​illegal ​acts or problems:
>
>   - *The ​director of Common Cause, a ​government ​watchdog ​group, said the court's ​action "​raises ​questions of favoritism."
>       The Civic Federation, a business-backed ​government ​watchdog, ​opposed the ​budget*.

From [The Internet, Democracy, and Democratization](https://books.google.it/books?id=2nyt8aGe04IC&pg=PA49&dq=%22political%20watchdog%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCGoVChMI0YernqzaxwIVQdoaCh1NRQoR#v=onepage&q=%22political%20watchdog%22&f=false):

> - As mentioned above, the gathering of data makes citizens wary ***and political watchdog groups vociferously attend to privacy issues*** even if the United States has weak privacy protection laws.

Comment: Glad to see we are marching in step again, Josh.

Answer (score 1):

In Britain it is quite normal and everyday to refer to a local or central- government supervisory body, informally, as a ***watchdog***.

In this [BBC report](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-21277094) you will see that the Independent Police Complaints Commission is referred to as *The Police Watchdog*.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to ask specifically about a body whose job is to watch normal citizens. The Police Watchdog watches over the police, which is a powerful body itself.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Well, if it is watching things like Wikipedia I wouldn't call them 'normal citizens'. The Press Complaints Commission, which does much the same thing against the excesses of newspaper proprietors is often referred to as ***the press watchdog***.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I agree with choster (in a comment above) that whether a person considers *watchdog* to be an appropriate term only as applied to an entity that defends (or warns) the public against (or of) government abuses is a matter of personal definition, not settled usage.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) leaves open the question of who properly benefits from a watchdog of the type we're discussing here, it seems to me:

> **watchdog** *n* (1612) **1 :** a dog kept to guard property **2 :** one that guards against loss, waste, theft, or undesirable practices

Definition 2 doesn't indicate who the watchdog is working for or who it is watching, and of course the answer to the question "What sorts of things constitute 'undesirable practices'?" depends to an overwhelming degree on who the watchdog's boss is.

It's easy to imagine a particular governmental entity (in Russia) that serves as the government's Internet watchdog by watching and reporting on private activity on the Internet. The government owns the watchdog, and the watchdog dutifully serves the government's interests—whether or not those interests coincide with the general public's. The government might even have the nerve to say that, in serving its interests, the watchdog is in a deeper sense serving the public interest.

In a true democracy, no doubt, one would expect a watchdog agency to have as its ultimate master the public and to have as its primary focus the practices and actions of some branch of the government. But I don't think that such an understanding is inherent in the term *watchdog*—not as Merriam-Webster defines it, anyway.